# How to extract a matrix of symbolic functions in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, symbolic-math

```
syms c  A(t) v(t)
A(t) =
            0
 c*sin(tt(t))
 c*cos(tt(t))
```

How I can get `X = A(2) = c*sin(tt(t));` (the function at second row)? If I type `A(2)`, the result will be as below (it substitutes a constant for the function, which is not my desire):

```
>> A(2)
ans =
            0
 c*sin(tt(2))
 c*cos(tt(2))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you've defined `A` as a symbolic function ([`symfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/symfun.html)), not as an array of symbolic expressions. Instead:

```
syms c A tt(t)
A = [0;
     c*sin(tt(t));
     c*sin(tt(t))];
```

Now `A(2)` will return `c*sin(tt(t))`.

Alternatively, if you can't change the definition of `A(t)`, you'll need to assign it to an intermediate variable to convert it to an array of symbolic expressions:

```
syms c  A(t) tt(t)
A(t) = [0;
        c*sin(tt(t));
        c*cos(tt(t))];
B = A(t);
```

Then, `B(2)` will return `c*sin(tt(t))`. You can also use [`formula`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/formula.html) to extract the underlying expressions:

```
B = formula(A):
```

Answer (score 0):

In matlab you must to use "subs(f)" function to evaluate functions.

First create the function:

```
syms g(x)
g(x) = x^3;
```

After that asign the X value:

```
x=2;
```

then if you evaluate g using the subs function, the result is the expected value 8, but it is assigned to a symbolic function, gnew. This new symbolic function formally depends on the variable x.

```
gnew = subs(g)
```

The function call, g(x), returns the value of g for the current value of x. For example, if you assigned the value 2 to the variable x, then calling g(x) is equivalent to calling g(2)

```
g2 = g(x)

g2 =
4

g2 = g(2)

g2 =
4
```

Comment: I just edit my question to make it clearer. I do not want to substitute a constant to the function.

Comment: I understood the problem and I think that is not easy to do that without change the function definition. Is possible to change the function to receive 2 parameters? in this way you can set the parameter 'a' = 2 and the 'b' parameter protect the function that you not want to change.